# how to configure primeng in webpack.config.js

Tags: angular, webpack, primeng

I'm new Angular 2 and primeNG as well i'm working on project which is configured with webpack server, now i want to use primeng for my project how can i do that.

I installed primeng using npm and imported the primeng module in appmodule and then tried to use the

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"></p-dropdown>
```

its showing error like

```
./~/primeng/components/accordion/accordion.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in \node_modules\primeng\components\accordion'
 @ ./~/primeng/components/accordion/accordion.js 13:19-49
 @ ./~/primeng/primeng.js
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./src/main.browser.ts

./~/primeng/components/confirmdialog/confirmdialog.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' \node_modules\primeng\components\confirmdialog'
 @ ./~/primeng/components/confirmdialog/confirmdialog.js 13:19-49
 @ ./~/primeng/primeng.js
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out? I am trying to configure my webpack to use primeNG.

Answer (score 0):

Look like '@angular/animations' is missing.

You could install via npm:

npm install @angular/animations --save

[Reference](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2303)

If the above is not working for you, then try to use the old release of PrimeNg (2.0.3)

npm install primeng@2.0.3 --save

[PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i've done that already, and failed. may be, i need set up webpack to support primeng i don't know how to do it, can you provide steps to to configure webpack to support primeng.

Comment: @GavishiddappaGadagi did you happen to figure this out. I am trying to configure out how to configure primeNG with webpack.

Comment: Yes I did it, you can install it with npm and import primng to vendor.ts file like import 'primeng/primeng'; and then include your vender.ts file path in the webpack.common.js file at entry point like this 'vendor': './src/vendor.ts', then start importing required modules in to your app @Drew1208

Comment: Also check this  [webpack-starter-project](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng-quickstart-webpack)  @Drew1208 Webpack starter project available in the github.